# First time using rails 5, trouble with tsort_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

it's my first time using Rails 5. I'm trying to run; rails s and it's giving me this:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.beta2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from block in tsort_each at /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
DEPRECATION WARNING: after_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use after_action instead. (called from block in tsort_each at /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from block in tsort_each at /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from block in tsort_each at /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
Exiting
/Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta2/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb:23:in `level': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:140:in `log_to_stdout'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:76:in `start'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/command.rb:20:in /`run'
  from /Users/ericcarpentier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:9:in `require'
  from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: do you have a before_filter or after_filter in any of your controllers or helpers?

Comment: No, I'm not using before_filter or after_filter for any of controller or helpers.

Comment: I commented out, the 'level' method in .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta2/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb and it temporily solved the problem but would like to find a permanent solution.

Comment: Following... I'm having the same issue. @RickRoberts workaround has it back up and running, but I don't want to deploy until this issue is resolved.

Comment: I created a github issue but but one of the rails core member says that it's due to 3rd party gem rails_12 factor. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23566

Answer (score 4):

In my Gemfile , I have:

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

and I am getting the same bug

I changed Gemfile to this:

```
group :production, :staging do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

bundle install and it works now.  Try it